# CloudWatch Logs agent stopped sending data from Jenkins log

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-cloudwatch

My cloudwatch logs stop sending data from the logstream i created for the jenkins.log. The error i am getting in /var/log/awslogs.log is the following code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/awslogs/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/var/awslogs/bin/aws", line 23, in main
return awscli.clidriver.main()
File "/var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py",   line 58, in main
driver = create_clidriver()
File "/var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 69, in create_clidriver
event_hooks=emitter)
File "/var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 49, in load_plugins
plugin.awscli_initialize(event_hooks)
File "/var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/__init__.py", line 25, in awscli_initialize
from cwlogs.pull import initialize as logs_pull_init
File "/var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/pull.py", line 22, in <module>
from awscli.customizations.service import Service
ImportError: No module named service
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install service package using pip?

```bash
pip install service
```